# Call a static method from abstract class

Tags: java

I have a class like this
parent class `DevPortalTestController` is `absract`

```
public class SeleniumWebDriverFactory extends DevPortalTestController {
    public static RemoteWebDriver mDriver;

    public SeleniumWebDriverFactory(RemoteWebDriver whichDriver)throws UnsupportedOSException, PoisonException {
        super(whichDriver);
        mDriver = whichDriver;
    }   

    public List<TestContext> getBrowserTestContext(List<String> browsers)
            throws Exception {
        PhoenixDriver driver = null;
        List<TestContext> contexts = new ArrayList<TestContext>();

        logger.info("Setting browser context...");

        Login login = retrieveLoginData();
        for (String browser : browsers) {
             // operations

             Map<String, Object> browserMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Populate the map with DevPortalTestController objects.
            browserMap.put(MasterConstants.BROWSER, this);

            .....
            .....
        }
        return contexts;
    }

public static List<TestContext> getTestContext(List<String> browsers)
        throws Exception {
    SeleniumWebDriverFactory instanceSel = new SeleniumWebDriverFactory(mDriver);
    List<TestContext> contexts = instanceSel.getBrowserTestContext(browsers);
    return contexts;
}
```

}

I need to call this `getTestContext` method in another class
for that am doing like this.Also that class is extenting another parnet class

```
public class DevPortalTest extends Test {


    RemoteWebDriver rmDriver ;
    SeleniumWebDriverFactory selFac =new SeleniumWebDriverFactory(rmDriver);


    @Override
    public List<TestContext> getTestContexts() {
        try {
            String os = System.getProperty("os.name");

            if (SystemDetail.deviceIsRunningWindows()) {
                return  selFac.getTestContext(ZucchiniConstants.allBrowsers);
           else {
                throw new TestException(os + " is not supported");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("", e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

But in this place

```
SeleniumWebDriverFactory selFac =new SeleniumWebDriverFactory(rmDriver);
```

I'm getting

> Default constructor cannot handle exception type PoisonException
>   thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit
>   constructor

How can i call the method `getTestContext` inside `DevPortalTest` test class?

Comment: you are actually calling super class construtctor here `public SeleniumWebDriverFactory(RemoteWebDriver whichDriver)throws UnsupportedOSException, PoisonException {
        super(whichDriver);
        mDriver = whichDriver;
    } `  

Define a empty (no argument) constructor.

Comment: Please include a minimal complete example; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: no argument constructor is not present in parent class...it a dependency class

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that initializer code will be placed in the "default constructor" which cannot throw any exception. Define an empty constructor that throws the exceptions to proceed.

e.g.,

```
DevPortalTest() throws UnsupportedOSException, PoisonException { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the constructor to your test code:

```
public DevPortalTest() throws UnsupportedOSException, PoisonException {
    SeleniumWebDriverFactory selFac = new SeleniumWebDriverFactory(rmDriver);
}
```

also, i assume you're injecting `RemoteWebDriver rmDriver;`

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is static, you don't need an object to call it.

```
SeleniumWebDriverFactory.getTestContext(ZucchiniConstants.allBrowsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a constructor you can also do this

```
public class DevPortalTest extends Test {

    RemoteWebDriver rmDriver ;
    SeleniumWebDriverFactory selFac;

    // this code block runs before constructor
    {
        try{
            selFac = new SeleniumWebDriverFactory(rmDriver);
        }catch(Exception e){
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Static method can be accessed using class Name so there is no need to create any Object in Abstract class.